# Validation of a phone number with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want the input to only allow numeric (`[0-9]`) characters and `+`, `(`, `)` and a space (). This validates a mobile number input field.

An example is: `+00 (000) 000 0000`

I already tried this:

```
if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
    $(this).val('');
} else {
```

Can somebody help me finding a regular expression to solve this?

Comment: My problem is  if i press space, this code clear my input :(

Comment: I need regex code like ı want

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that others don't have to read the comments to understand. I'd suggest that you also take the time to read the "*[ask]*" guidance.

Comment: @YavuzSelimÖzmen I've edited your question to a proper English. I hope I didn't change the meaning of your question.

Comment: "My problem is if i press space, this code clear my input"...that's because of the `$(this).val('');` line. What do you want to do? Just delete the faulty character? I really think you'd be better to use a proper regular expression to try and validate the line. Then you can ensure that not only the correct characters are used, but that they're located in the correct place in the string. Have you used regular expressions before?

Comment: "+00 (000) 000 0000" — That does not match the format of my mobile phone number.

Answer (score 3):

Please check following will help you on the validation of Phone Number.
Also you can various filtering by using the different input masks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input
    id="phone-number"
    name="phone-number"
    type="text" class="masked"
    placeholder="+xx (xxx) xxx xxxx"
    pattern="+\d{2} (\d{3}) \d{3} \d{4}"
    title="Enter valid phone number" />

  <script data-autoinit="true">
    var InputMask = function (opts) {
      if (opts && opts.masked) {
        // Make it easy to wrap this plugin and pass elements instead of a selector
        opts.masked = typeof opts.masked === string ? document.querySelectorAll(opts.masked) : opts.masked;
      }

      if (opts) {
        this.opts = {
          masked: opts.masked || document.querySelectorAll(this.d.masked),
          mNum: opts.mNum || this.d.mNum,
          mChar: opts.mChar || this.d.mChar,
          error: opts.onError || this.d.onError
        }
      } else {
        this.opts = this.d;
        this.opts.masked = document.querySelectorAll(this.opts.masked);
      }

      this.refresh(true);
    };

    var inputMask = {

      // Default Values
      d: {
        masked: '.masked',
        mNum: '*xdDmMyY9',
        mChar: '_',
        onError: function () { }
      },

      refresh: function (init) {
        var t, parentClass;

        if (!init) {
          this.opts.masked = document.querySelectorAll(this.opts.masked);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < this.opts.masked.length; i++) {
          t = this.opts.masked[i]
          parentClass = t.parentNode.getAttribute('class');

          if (!parentClass || (parentClass && parentClass.indexOf('shell') === -1)) {
            this.createShell(t);
            this.activateMasking(t);
          }
        }
      },

      // replaces each masked t with a shall containing the t and it's mask.
      createShell: function (t) {
        var wrap = document.createElement('span'),
          mask = document.createElement('span'),
          emphasis = document.createElement('i'),
          tClass = t.getAttribute('class'),
          pTxt = t.getAttribute('placeholder'),
          placeholder = document.createTextNode(pTxt === '****' ? '***' : pTxt);

        t.setAttribute('maxlength', pTxt.length);
        t.setAttribute('data-placeholder', pTxt);
        t.removeAttribute('placeholder');


        if (!tClass || (tClass && tClass.indexOf('masked') === -1)) {
          t.setAttribute('class', tClass + ' masked');
        }

        mask.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
        mask.setAttribute('id', t.getAttribute('id') + 'Mask');
        mask.appendChild(emphasis);
        mask.appendChild(placeholder);

        wrap.setAttribute('class', 'shell');
        t.parentNode.insertBefore(wrap, t);
        wrap.appendChild(t);
        wrap.appendChild(mask);
      },

      setValueOfMask: function (e) {
        var value = e.target.value,
          placeholder = e.target.getAttribute('data-placeholder');

        return "<i>" + value + "</i>" + (placeholder === '****' ? '***' : placeholder).substr(value.length);
      },

      // add event listeners
      activateMasking: function (t) {
        var that = this;
        if (t.addEventListener) { // remove "if" after death of IE 8
          t.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            that.handleValueChange.call(that, e);
          }, false);
        } else if (t.attachEvent) { // For IE 8
          t.attachEvent('onkeyup', function (e) {
            e.target = e.srcElement;
            that.handleValueChange.call(that, e);
          });
        }
      },

      handleValueChange: function (e) {
        var id = e.target.getAttribute('id');

        if (e.target.value == document.querySelector('#' + id + 'Mask i').innerHTML) {
          return; // Continue only if value hasn't changed
        }

        document.getElementById(id).value = this.handleCurrentValue(e);
        document.getElementById(id + 'Mask').innerHTML = this.setValueOfMask(e);

      },

      handleCurrentValue: function (e) {
        var isCharsetPresent = e.target.getAttribute('data-charset'),
          placeholder = isCharsetPresent || e.target.getAttribute('data-placeholder'),
          value = e.target.value, l = placeholder.length, newValue = '',
          i, j, isInt, isLetter, strippedValue;

        // strip special characters
        strippedValue = isCharsetPresent ? value.replace(/\W/g, "") : value.replace(/\D/g, "");

        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < l; i++) {
          isInt = !isNaN(parseInt(strippedValue[j]));
          isLetter = strippedValue[j] ? strippedValue[j].match(/[A-Z]/i) : false;
          matchesNumber = this.opts.mNum.indexOf(placeholder[i]) >= 0;
          matchesLetter = this.opts.mChar.indexOf(placeholder[i]) >= 0;
          if ((matchesNumber && isInt) || (isCharsetPresent && matchesLetter && isLetter)) {
            newValue += strippedValue[j++];
          } else if ((!isCharsetPresent && !isInt && matchesNumber) || (isCharsetPresent && ((matchesLetter && !isLetter) || (matchesNumber && !isInt)))) {
            //this.opts.onError( e ); // write your own error handling function
            return newValue;
          } else {
            newValue += placeholder[i];
          }
          // break if no characters left and the pattern is non-special character
          if (strippedValue[j] == undefined) {
            break;
          }
        }
        if (e.target.getAttribute('data-valid-example')) {
          return this.validateProgress(e, newValue);
        }
        return newValue;
      },

      validateProgress: function (e, value) {
        var validExample = e.target.getAttribute('data-valid-example'),
          pattern = new RegExp(e.target.getAttribute('pattern')),
          placeholder = e.target.getAttribute('data-placeholder'),
          l = value.length, testValue = '';

        //convert to months
        if (l == 1 && placeholder.toUpperCase().substr(0, 2) == 'MM') {
          if (value > 1 && value < 10) {
            value = '0' + value;
          }
          return value;
        }
        // test the value, removing the last character, until what you have is a submatch
        for (i = l; i >= 0; i--) {
          testValue = value + validExample.substr(value.length);
          if (pattern.test(testValue)) {
            return value;
          } else {
            value = value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
          }
        }

        return value;
      }
    };

    for (var property in inputMask) {
      if (inputMask.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        InputMask.prototype[property] = inputMask[property];
      }
    }

    //  Declaritive initalization
    (function () {
      var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
        script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
      if (script.getAttribute('data-autoinit')) {
        new InputMask();
      }
    })();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

*There are many similar questions like yours, please do a search on StackOverflow first next time, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation).*

---

You could try the following simple regex, which only checks for the characters you listed:

```
^[0-9+() ]+$
```

- `^` and `$` enforce the whole string to be your matching pattern
- `[0-9+() ]+` defines a set of your characters which need to occur at least once

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/t2oAF6/1